# Adding assertion functionality to python logging module?

Tags: python, logging, assert

I use assertions a lot in my code, and I would like to log any assertion errors that I have. After googling the problem, I didn't find a convenient solution.

So what I came up with is I added a method to logging.Logger class.

```py
import logging

def assertion(self, bool_condition, message):
    try:
        assert bool_condition, message
    except AssertionError:
        self.exception(message)
        raise

logging.Logger.assertion = assertion

""" apply log config """

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.assertion(1 == 2, 'Assertion failed.')
```

It seems to do the job but I was wondering if it is a good practice to do so.